# caching the result from a [n async] factory method iff it doesn't throw

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task, lazy-evaluation

UPDATE: Heavily revised after @usr pointed out I'd incorrectly assumed `Lazy<T>`'s default thread safety mode was `LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly`...

I want to lazily compute a value via an `async` Factory Method (i.e. it returns `Task<T>`) and have it cached upon success. On exception, I want to have that be available to me. I do not however, want to fall prey to [the exception caching behavior](http://theburningmonk.com/2013/04/be-lazy-but-be-ware-of-initialization-exception/) that `Lazy<T>` has in its default mode (`LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication`)

> Exception caching:  When you use factory methods, exceptions are cached. That is, if the factory method throws an exception the first time a thread tries to access the Value property of the Lazy object, the same exception is thrown on every subsequent attempt. This ensures that every call to the Value property produces the same result and avoids subtle errors that might arise if different threads get different results. The Lazy stands in for an actual T that otherwise would have been initialized at some earlier point, usually during startup. A failure at that earlier point is usually fatal. If there is a potential for a recoverable failure, we recommend that you build the retry logic into the initialization routine (in this case, the factory method), just as you would if you weren’t using lazy initialization.

[Stephen Toub has an `AsyncLazy` class and writeup](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/15/asynclazy-lt-t-gt.aspx) that seems just right:

```
public class AsyncLazy<T> : Lazy<Task<T>>
{
    public AsyncLazy(Func<Task<T>> taskFactory) :
        base(() => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => taskFactory()).Unwrap())
    { }

    public TaskAwaiter<T> GetAwaiter() { return Value.GetAwaiter(); }
}
```

however that's effectively the same behavior as a default `Lazy<T>` - if there's a problem, there will be no retries.

I'm looking for a `Task<T>` compatible equivalent of `Lazy<T>(Func<T>, LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly)`, i.e. it should behave as that is specified:-

> Alternative to locking  In certain situations, you might want to avoid the overhead of the Lazy object's default locking behavior. In rare situations, there might be a potential for deadlocks. In such cases, you can use the Lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode) or Lazy(Func, LazyThreadSafetyMode) constructor, and specify LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly. This enables the Lazy object to create a copy of the lazily initialized object on each of several threads if the threads call the Value property simultaneously. The Lazy object ensures that all threads use the same instance of the lazily initialized object and discards the instances that are not used. Thus, the cost of reducing the locking overhead is that your program might sometimes create and discard extra copies of an expensive object. In most cases, this is unlikely. The examples for the Lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode) and Lazy(Func, LazyThreadSafetyMode) constructors demonstrate this behavior.
>
> IMPORTANT
>
> When you specify PublicationOnly, exceptions are never cached, even if you specify a factory method.

Is there any FCL, `Nito.AsyncEx` or similar construct that might fit in nicely here? Failing this, can anyone see an elegant way to gate the "attempt in progress" bit (I'm OK with each caller making its own attempt in the same way that a `Lazy<T>(` ..., `(LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly)` does) and yet still have that and the cache management encapsulated neatly?

Comment: LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication is poison. It stores the exception and fails forever. Completely unsuitable for production use. Requires human intervention to restore service (restart app). In case you want to use this for a cache, PublicationOnly leads to cache stampeding and should not be used. So what you really need is ExecutionAndPublication except for the deadly exception caching.

Comment: @usr +1000 Yes, that explains succinctly the semantics I'd like my `AsyncLazyWithRetries` (and a new `Lazy<T>` `LazyThreadSafetyMode.Unicorn`) to have.

Comment: What do you ultimately want to cache? The `Task` returned from the `Func`, or the result returned from the `Task`? (Looking at the code in your answer, I'm guessing you want to cache the result returned from the `Task`, but only if there have been no exceptions along the way. Is that right?)

Comment: @LukeH Yes, I see little point in caching the `Task` itself, as its result will be "baked in" as `Task<T>`'s [nature is to be 'hot'](http://tomasp.net/blog/async-csharp-differences.aspx/). Obviously it would be useful to have a gate that prevents >1 simultaneous initialization event. I'd even quibble with Stephen's contention that one should want to run the factory method on a separate thread - a key design constraint implied by this model is that a `*Async` method should not do much inline processing before returning the `Task`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this get anywhere near your requirements?

The behaviour falls somewhere between `ExecutionAndPublication` and `PublicationOnly`.

While the initializer is in-flight all calls to `Value` will be handed the same task (which is cached temporarily but could subsequently succeed or fail); if the initializer succeeds then that completed task is cached permanently; if the initializer fails then the next call to `Value` will create a completely new initialization task and the process begins again!

```
public sealed class TooLazy<T>
{
    private readonly object _lock = new object();
    private readonly Func<Task<T>> _factory;
    private Task<T> _cached;

    public TooLazy(Func<Task<T>> factory)
    {
        if (factory == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("factory");
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public Task<T> Value
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if ((_cached == null) ||
                    (_cached.IsCompleted && (_cached.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)))
                {
                    _cached = Task.Run(_factory);
                }
                return _cached;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks great. Your use of *discarded* threw me initially; May I suggest amending your comment:- s/discarded/will trigger reinitialization with a fresh (retry) attempt by the first caller coming through the gate after the request has transitioned to `Faulted`/. Actually scratch all that - your mainline text describes it perfectly and isnt that long; just delete the TL;DR :P

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer:** This is a wild attempt at refactoring `Lazy<T>`. It is in no way production grade code.

I took the liberty of looking at `Lazy<T>` source code and modifying it a bit to work with `Func<Task<T>>`. I've refactored the `Value` property to become a `FetchValueAsync` method since we can't await inside a property. You are free to block the `async` operation with `Task.Result` so you can still use the `Value` property, I didn't want to do that because it may lead to problems. So it's a little bit more cumbersome, but still works. This code is not fully tested:

```
public class AsyncLazy<T>
{
    static class LazyHelpers
    {
        internal static readonly object PUBLICATION_ONLY_SENTINEL = new object();
    }
    class Boxed
    {
        internal Boxed(T value)
        {
            this.value = value;
        }
        internal readonly T value;
    }

    class LazyInternalExceptionHolder
    {
        internal ExceptionDispatchInfo m_edi;
        internal LazyInternalExceptionHolder(Exception ex)
        {
            m_edi = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex);
        }
    }

    static readonly Func<Task<T>> alreadyInvokedSentinel = delegate
    {
        Contract.Assert(false, "alreadyInvokedSentinel should never be invoked.");
        return default(Task<T>);
    };

    private object boxed;

    [NonSerialized]
    private Func<Task<T>> valueFactory;

    [NonSerialized]
    private object threadSafeObj;

    public AsyncLazy()
        : this(LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication)
    {
    }
    public AsyncLazy(Func<Task<T>> valueFactory)
                : this(valueFactory, LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication)
    {
    }

    public AsyncLazy(bool isThreadSafe) :
                this(isThreadSafe ?
                     LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication :
                     LazyThreadSafetyMode.None)
    {
    }

    public AsyncLazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
    {
        threadSafeObj = GetObjectFromMode(mode);
    }

    public AsyncLazy(Func<Task<T>> valueFactory, bool isThreadSafe)
                : this(valueFactory, isThreadSafe ? LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication : LazyThreadSafetyMode.None)
    {
    }

    public AsyncLazy(Func<Task<T>> valueFactory, LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
    {
        if (valueFactory == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("valueFactory");

        threadSafeObj = GetObjectFromMode(mode);
        this.valueFactory = valueFactory;
    }

    private static object GetObjectFromMode(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
    {
        if (mode == LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication)
            return new object();
        if (mode == LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly)
            return LazyHelpers.PUBLICATION_ONLY_SENTINEL;
        if (mode != LazyThreadSafetyMode.None)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("mode");

        return null; // None mode
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return IsValueCreated ? ((Boxed) boxed).value.ToString() : "NoValue";
    }

    internal LazyThreadSafetyMode Mode
    {
        get
        {
            if (threadSafeObj == null) return LazyThreadSafetyMode.None;
            if (threadSafeObj == (object)LazyHelpers.PUBLICATION_ONLY_SENTINEL) return LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly;
            return LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication;
        }
    }
    internal bool IsValueFaulted
    {
        get { return boxed is LazyInternalExceptionHolder; }
    }

    public bool IsValueCreated
    {
        get
        {
            return boxed != null && boxed is Boxed;
        }
    }

    public async Task<T> FetchValueAsync()
    {
        Boxed boxed = null;
        if (this.boxed != null)
        {
            // Do a quick check up front for the fast path.
            boxed = this.boxed as Boxed;
            if (boxed != null)
            {
                return boxed.value;
            }

            LazyInternalExceptionHolder exc = this.boxed as LazyInternalExceptionHolder;
            exc.m_edi.Throw();
        }

        return await LazyInitValue().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// local helper method to initialize the value 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The inititialized T value</returns>
    private async Task<T> LazyInitValue()
    {
        Boxed boxed = null;
        LazyThreadSafetyMode mode = Mode;
        if (mode == LazyThreadSafetyMode.None)
        {
            boxed = await CreateValue().ConfigureAwait(false);
            this.boxed = boxed;
        }
        else if (mode == LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly)
        {
            boxed = await CreateValue().ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (boxed == null ||
                Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this.boxed, boxed, null) != null)
            {
                boxed = (Boxed)this.boxed;
            }
            else
            {
                valueFactory = alreadyInvokedSentinel;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            object threadSafeObject = Volatile.Read(ref threadSafeObj);
            bool lockTaken = false;
            try
            {
                if (threadSafeObject != (object)alreadyInvokedSentinel)
                    Monitor.Enter(threadSafeObject, ref lockTaken);
                else
                    Contract.Assert(this.boxed != null);

                if (this.boxed == null)
                {
                    boxed = await CreateValue().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    this.boxed = boxed;
                    Volatile.Write(ref threadSafeObj, alreadyInvokedSentinel);
                }
                else
                {
                    boxed = this.boxed as Boxed;
                    if (boxed == null) // it is not Boxed, so it is a LazyInternalExceptionHolder
                    {
                        LazyInternalExceptionHolder exHolder = this.boxed as LazyInternalExceptionHolder;
                        Contract.Assert(exHolder != null);
                        exHolder.m_edi.Throw();
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (lockTaken)
                    Monitor.Exit(threadSafeObject);
            }
        }
        Contract.Assert(boxed != null);
        return boxed.value;
    }

    /// <summary>Creates an instance of T using valueFactory in case its not null or use reflection to create a new T()</summary>
    /// <returns>An instance of Boxed.</returns>
    private async Task<Boxed> CreateValue()
    {
        Boxed localBoxed = null;
        LazyThreadSafetyMode mode = Mode;
        if (valueFactory != null)
        {
            try
            {
                // check for recursion
                if (mode != LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly && valueFactory == alreadyInvokedSentinel)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Recursive call to Value property");

                Func<Task<T>> factory = valueFactory;
                if (mode != LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly) // only detect recursion on None and ExecutionAndPublication modes
                {
                    valueFactory = alreadyInvokedSentinel;
                }
                else if (factory == alreadyInvokedSentinel)
                {
                    // Another thread ----d with us and beat us to successfully invoke the factory.
                    return null;
                }
                localBoxed = new Boxed(await factory().ConfigureAwait(false));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (mode != LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly) // don't cache the exception for PublicationOnly mode
                    boxed = new LazyInternalExceptionHolder(ex);
                throw;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                localBoxed = new Boxed((T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)));
            }
            catch (MissingMethodException)
            {
                Exception ex = new MissingMemberException("Missing parametersless constructor");
                if (mode != LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly) // don't cache the exception for PublicationOnly mode
                    boxed = new LazyInternalExceptionHolder(ex);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        return localBoxed;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I can picture that working. However, I can't see myself foisting a code splurge of that size that on my succesors,  so I hope you'll pardon the lack of an accept :P

Comment: @RubenBartelink Of course, I understand, I wouldn't take that either ;P. Just wanted to see how much effort it would take to transform this to something that supports asynchronous operations, and thought I'd share the attempt.

Comment: rewriting the question. I'd be fine with a weaker guarantee like  `LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly` offers which removes the need for a lot of stuff

Comment: @RubenBartelink You're probably right. I'll have a go at it later, see what comes out.

Comment: Thanks Yuval! Assuming usr doesnt get me to delete the question completely, it would be nice to have an answer of ready-to-go-into-Nito.AsycEx level completeness :)

Answer (score 1):

For now, I am using this:

```
public class CachedAsync<T>
{
    readonly Func<Task<T>> _taskFactory;
    T _value;

    public CachedAsync(Func<Task<T>> taskFactory)
    {
        _taskFactory = taskFactory;
    }

    public TaskAwaiter<T> GetAwaiter() { return Fetch().GetAwaiter(); }

    async Task<T> Fetch()
    {
        if (_value == null)
            _value = await _taskFactory();
        return _value;
    }
}
```

While it works in my scenario (I don't have multiple triggering threads etc.), it's hardly elegant and doesn't provide thread-safe coordination of either

- a single attempt in progress a la `LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication`
  OR
- a stable result after >= 1 success a la `LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly`

Answer (score 0):

Version as I am using based on [@LukeH's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33942013/584676):

```
// http://stackoverflow.com/a/33872589/11635
public class LazyTask
{
    public static LazyTask<T> Create<T>(Func<Task<T>> factory)
    {
        return new LazyTask<T>(factory);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Implements a caching/provisioning model we can term LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublicationWithoutFailureCaching
/// - Ensures only a single provisioning attempt in progress
/// - a successful result gets locked in
/// - a failed result triggers replacement by the first caller through the gate to observe the failed state
///</summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Inspired by Stephen Toub http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/15/asynclazy-lt-t-gt.aspx
/// Implemented with sensible semantics by @LukeH via SO http://stackoverflow.com/a/33942013/11635
/// </remarks>
public class LazyTask<T>
{
    readonly object _lock = new object();
    readonly Func<Task<T>> _factory;
    Task<T> _cached;

    public LazyTask(Func<Task<T>> factory)
    {
        if (factory == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("factory");
        _factory = factory;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allow await keyword to be applied directly as if it was a Task<T>. See Value for semantics.
    /// </summary>
    public TaskAwaiter<T> GetAwaiter()
    {
        return Value.GetAwaiter();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Trigger a load attempt. If there is an attempt in progress, take that. If preceding attempt failed, trigger a retry.
    /// </summary>
    public Task<T> Value
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_lock) 
                if (_cached == null || BuildHasCompletedButNotSucceeded())
                    _cached = _factory();
            return _cached;
        }
    }

    bool BuildHasCompletedButNotSucceeded()
    {
        return _cached.IsCompleted && _cached.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion;
    }
}
```

Comment: @LukeH I think it has pretty much earned the name that Stephen Toub's original one didnt IMO, ***EDIT** but I'm calling it AsyncLazy so as not to clash with the name of that, or [the derived version in `Nito.AsyncEx`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17975972/11635)*. If I was feeling cheeky rather than just very grateful for your clean impl, I'd edit this into your answer

Comment: @StephenCleary What would you think about putting this into `Nito.AsyncEx` (unless you can find holes in it). Would you be open to a PR from me OR Luke? Or would you prefer to impl it yourself in Nito style? (EDIT: I realize you have a `Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncLazy`; as discussed in the OP, for me the semantics are worse than useless for my case). Alternate names: `LazyAsync`, `LazyRetryingTask`

Comment: I should emphasise that I barely tested my version *at all*. I think it should be ok in most sane situations, although I'd be very interested in any criticisms/improvements from the experts out there. I'm also keen to know if it's possible to get roughly the same semantics using `async`/`await`, rather than throwing the factory onto the thread-pool with `Task.Run`.

Comment: @LukeH On reflection, I'll probably take out the `Task.Run` on the basis that deferring heavy stuff should be part of the 'ground rules of a `*Async` method'. Obviously async/await clashes with it being a property (and I'm not sure what you're referring to specifically).

Comment: I was thinking about how to gracefully handle (without `Task.Run`) the situation where the task creation itself is potentially time-consuming. But I think you're right: it's reasonable to assume that the task creation will be near-instantaneous and all the heavy-lifting will be handled by the running task. Your edit covers that nicely, imo.

Comment: Thanks; I guess ultimately, the consumer can do the wrapping, which upholds SRP and compositionality => s/`taskFactory`/`taskFactory >> Task.Run`/ :)