# Is Task == Lazy?

Tags: c#, .net

```
public Data GetCurrent(Credentials credentials)
{ 
    var data = new Lazy<Data>(() => GetCurrentInternal(credentials));
    try
    {
        return data.Value;
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        throw ex.InnerException;
    }
}
```

If I change the call to the following:

```
var data = new Task<Data>(() => GetCurrentInternal(credentials));
```

Is there anything change? Should I prefer `Task` over `Lazy`? What about `Dispose()` and `catch(Exception)` ?

Comment: Why do you want to use `Lazy` in first place? It make no sense to initialize local variable. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6847721/1997232).

Comment: `Task` and `Lazy` are completely different classes and concepts - unrelated to each other. What behaviour do you want?

Comment: Don't be lazy, read the documentation... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Using a Task like that doesn't compile so the entire question seems a bit hypothetical.

Comment: It compile if I change `.Value => .Result`

Comment: What's your query about `Dispose` and `catch`?

Comment: Here OP seems really lazy to check in the specification.

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko, care to answer my question? I am curious who told you to write such method or where did you get the idea to ask then such a un-deliberated (in my opinion) question which many think is a good one.

Comment: If you use `Task` it will throw an `AggregationException` that wraps any exceptions thrown by the enclosed code.

Comment: @juharr Thanks, for constructive answer

Comment: When you rethrow an inner exception like you do in your code you lose the stack trace making it hard to understand where the original exception occured. In general, don't rethrow exceptions like that. Either 1) catch it and handle it, 2) catch it and rethrow it as a new exception with the caught exception as the inner exception or 3) if you really want to rethrow the original exception (like if you want to log during exception unwinding) use `throw` in the `catch` block without specifying any exception to rethrow the original exception.

Comment: @MartinLiversage Thank you very much!

Comment: You are doing your taxes. `Lazy<T>` is "I might not need to compute my charitable contributions this year so I am going to put off doing that work as long as possible, in the hopes that I don't have to do it at all. But if I do have to, I will remember the result I computed so that I don't have to do it again."  `Task<T>` is "my darling, while I am doing this other calculation can you work out our charitable contributions? Let me know when you're done, and I may or may not end up using your work. Regardless, once you're done, remember what the result was."

Comment: I learnt a lot from the contrast with F#'s Async in this article http://tomasp.net/blog/csharp-async-gotchas.aspx/

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872588/caching-the-result-from-a-n-async-factory-method-iff-it-doesnt-throw/33874601

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Similarities

Both `Lazy<T>` and `Task<T>` promise to do some work later and return a result of type `T`.

## Differences

`Lazy<T>` promises to do its work as late as possible if it is required at all, and does so synchronously.

`Task<T>` however can do its work asynchronously while your thread does other work, or blocks awaiting result.

`Lazy<T>` will bubble up any exception caused by the lambda when you call `.Value`.

`Task<T>` will keep any exception caused by the lambda and throw it later when you `await task`. Or if you `task.Wait()` it *may* wrap the exception in an `AggregationException`. I refer you to this for more info on catching exceptions thrown by tasks: [Catch an exception thrown by an async method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383310/catch-an-exception-thrown-by-an-async-method) and this http://stiller.co.il/blog/2012/12/task-wait-vs-await/

Comment: there is another similarty: both does no sense in the supplied code.

Comment: And I need to call Dispose if I use Task inside finally. Am I right?

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko Probably not please read  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/25/10287435.aspx

Comment: CA2000 Dispose objects before losing scope. ... before all references to it are out of scope.

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko Just suppress the CA warning.  It's not going to stop you from compiling the code.

Comment: @weston Code Analysis is part of Visual Studio.  It use to be in a separate MS product called FXCop.

Comment: @juharr yes, but if I will use `Lazy` I will not suppress anything

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko So?  Are you saying that should be listed as a difference?

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko The two classes are different tools for different jobs. Don't let CA dictate which is appropriate for you.

Comment: Right, that's a bug in the analyzer that really ought to be fixed. It should suppress the warning when the disposable is a task.

Comment: @juharr didn't know that thanks. Bit shocking that Task causes this warning.

Answer (score 12):

No, `Lazy<T>` is not the same as `Task<T>`.

---

[`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) is an implementation of the concept of [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation):

1. It represents a `T` value that will be **computed synchronously at first access**, which may or may not occur at all.
2. Evaluation happens at first access, and **subsequent accesses use a cached value**. [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) is a closely related concept.
3. The first access will block in order to compute the value, while subsequent accesses will yield the value immediately.

---

[`Task<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424(v=vs.110).aspx) is related to the concept of a [future](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises).

1. It represents a `T` value that will be **computed (typically asynchronously) at the creation of its [promise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises)**, even if nobody ends up actually accessing it.
2. **All accesses yield a cached value** that has been or will be computed by the evaluation mechanism (the promise) at a prior or future time.
3. Any access that occurs before the computation of the value has finished will block until the calculation is complete. Any access that occurs after the computation of the value has finished will immediately yield the computed value.

---

All that being said, `Lazy<T>` and `Task<T>` do have something in common that you may have already picked up.

Each of these types is **a unary generic type that describes a unique way to perform a particular computation** that would yield a `T` value (and that computation can conveniently be passed as a delegate or lambda). In other words, **each of these types is an example of a [monad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming))**. You can find some very [good and simple explanations of what a monad is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2704795/1892179) here on Stack Overflow and elsewhere.

Comment: Oh, it's a monad all right -- or, more accurately, a comonad. The C# type system has no problem creating types that use the monad pattern. The concept that the C# type system lacks is there is no way to say "I'd like to make a method whose arguments are only generic types that match the monad pattern".

Comment: @Thomas Great answer!

Answer (score 4):

`Task` and `Lazy` are completely different concepts.

You use Task to do asynchronous operations. Some boring MSDN:

> The Task class represents a single operation that does not return a
>   value and that usually executes asynchronously. Task objects are one
>   of the central components of the task-based asynchronous pattern first
>   introduced in the .NET Framework 4. Because the work performed by a
>   Task object typically executes asynchronously on a thread pool thread
>   rather than synchronously on the main application thread, you can use
>   the Status property, as well as the IsCanceled, IsCompleted, and
>   IsFaulted properties, to determine the state of a task. Most commonly,
>   a lambda expression is used to specify the work that the task is to
>   perform.

Lazy is used for deferred initialization of an object. It means, that your object gets initialized only when you call `lazyObj.Value`.

> Use lazy initialization to defer the creation of a large or
>   resource-intensive object, or the execution of a resource-intensive
>   task, particularly when such creation or execution might not occur
>   during the lifetime of the program.
>
> To prepare for lazy initialization, you create an instance of Lazy.
>   The type argument of the Lazy object that you create specifies the
>   type of the object that you want to initialize lazily. The constructor
>   that you use to create the Lazy object determines the
>   characteristics of the initialization. Lazy initialization occurs the
>   first time the Lazy.Value property is accessed.

Comment: `Task` need not be asynchronous, `TaskCompletionSource<T>` as one example.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov that is true. Not necessarily for task to be async.