# Make concurrent await calls for the same promise wait for the first call to fulfill only once

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve exactly [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41707025/how-to-make-different-calls-to-an-async-method-waiting-for-the-result-of-first-c) but in ES2020.

Let's say I have a promise that resolves after one second, and several `await`s for that promise, called concurrently from different places. The promise must settle only once, and the `await`s should return its result. In the code below, I want all callers to get `1`.

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

let counter = 0;
async function getSomething() {
  await sleep(1000);
  return ++counter;
}

(async function caller1() {
  console.log(await getSomething());
})();

(async function caller2() {
  console.log(await getSomething());
})();

(async function caller3() {
  console.log(await getSomething());
})();
```

How can I do that?

Comment: The issue is that the function `getSomething` is returning a NEW promise every time it is called, so each of your calling functions is awaiting separate ones. You could do something like `const something = getSomething(); (async function caller1() { console.log(await something); })(); (async function caller2() { console.log(await something); })();` and `caller2` will end up evaluating the same Promise as `caller1`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest pattern is to take advantage of the fact that promises only settle once, and rewrite `getSomething` like this:

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

let counter = 0;
let promise;
async function getSomething() {
  // If another invocation has already initialized the promise, return that promise
  if (promise)
    return promise;
  // Otherwise, we're the first invocation, so initialize the promise...
  promise = sleep(1000).then(() => ++counter);
  // ...and return it
  return promise;
}

(async function caller1() {
  console.log(await getSomething());
})();

(async function caller2() {
  console.log(await getSomething());
})();

(async function caller3() {
  console.log(await getSomething());
})();
```